# React MUI use custom Theme attribute in component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to center a `CircularProgress` element and I thought making the style reusable would be cool, so I created a theme.d.ts:

```
import { Theme, ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material/styles'

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface CustomTheme extends Theme {
    marginAutoItem: {
      margin: string;
    };
  }
  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface CustomThemeOptions extends ThemeOptions {
    marginAutoItem: {
      margin?: string;
    };
  }
  export function createTheme(options?: CustomThemeOptions): CustomTheme;
}
```

Then I have this:

```
const theme = responsiveFontSizes(createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#626262",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#DFDFDF",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Arial Regular',
      'sans'
    ].join(','),
  },
  marginAutoItem: {
    margin: 'auto'
  }
}));

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container as Element);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Now I wish to add this new `marginAutoItem` to a component; how do I do that?

```
// pseudocode in a sense
<CircularProgress marginAutoItem />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MUI component **sx** property. See [documentation](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/).

For example:

```
<CircularProgress
    sx={ {
        margin: ( theme ) => theme.marginAutoItem.margin
    } }
/>
```